# SVG - how to clip google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <title>Map</title>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
            var map;
            function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                    mapOptions);

            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #eee">
        <svg id="svg-container" width="700" height="500" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

            <clipPath id="cut-off">
                <polygon points="100,50 300,75 400,25 500,150 690,180 690,240 480,380 510,410 560,410 460,490 410,420 450,380 350,360 280,430 240,430 290,340 220,250 110,260 10,230 110,110" />
            </clipPath>

            <polygon points="100,50 300,75 400,25 500,150 690,180 690,240 480,380 510,410 560,410 460,490 410,420 450,380 350,360 280,430 240,430 290,340 220,250 110,260 10,230 110,110" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="white" />

            <foreignobject x="0" y="0" width="700" height="500" clip-path="url(#cut-off)" >
                <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
                </body>
            </foreignObject>
        </svg>

    </body>
</html>
```

It must cut google map, but it works only in Firefox. In Opera, for example, map is over SVG path. If you know, how to solve this for other browsers, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: If you make the foreignObject a child of a `<g>` or `<svg>` element and apply the clip on that parent element does that fix it?

Comment: no. the map is still on top.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem - @alex: did you find any cross-browser solution?

Comment: no. map is still on top. i have made images mask over it.